# Z3, C++: pointer being freed was not allocated

Tags: c++, z3

I decided to use Z3 with C ++ and installed the latest version from git. When trying the git sample, (The following code is a simplified sample)

```
#include "z3++.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace z3;
using namespace std;

int main() {
    context c;
    expr x = c.bool_const("x");
    expr y = c.bool_const("y");
    expr conjunction = (!(x && y)) == (!x|| !y);
    solver s(c);

    s.add(!conjunction);
    cout << s << "\n";
    cout << s.to_smt2() << "\n";
    switch (s.check()) {
        case unsat:   std::cout << "de-Morgan is valid\n"; break;
        case sat:     std::cout << "de-Morgan is not valid\n"; break;
        case unknown: std::cout << "unknown\n"; break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I could get this result.

```
(declare-fun y () Bool)
(declare-fun x () Bool)
(assert (not (= (not (and x y)) (or (not x) (not y)))))

;
(set-info :status unknown)
(declare-fun y () Bool)
(declare-fun x () Bool)
(assert
 (not (= (not (and x y)) (or (not x) (not y)))))
(check-sat)

de-Morgan is valid
```

But I got this error.

```
a.out(92870,0x7fff9182c380) malloc: *** error for object 0x7f7fdc6217f8: pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
Abort trap: 6
```

From this it turned out that this error occurred after the program terminated. We also found that this error occurs by referring to the already released constructor, but we do not see such a point in this sample.

Those who are experts, thank you.

Comment: When you say "simplified sample", do you mean that the code in your question does have the problem, or that it's an approximation that doesn't?

Comment: The words "released constructor" do not mean anything in relation to C++. Do you mean  "destroyed object" or is it a Z3 term?

Comment: I cannot replicate this; running it works just fine. Your installation of z3 might be busted; I'd recommend installing z3 from scratch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From a C++ perspective, you seem to be doing everything correctly.  Furthermore, you copied directly from the [Z++ example.cpp](https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/blob/master/examples/c%2B%2B/example.cpp).

SUGGESTION:

Even though it *shouldn't* make a difference... please try this:

a) copy your code *OUT* of `main()` and into a separate function, `demorgan()`

b) Wrap your call from "main()" into "demorgan()" from a `try {} catch()` block

Or even better... try running the entire example.cpp as-is, with no changes.

Failing all else, one (silly!) workaround: `context *c = new context();`: instead of "auto", try "new" and see what happens.

Q: What compiler are you using?  What platform are you building on?

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way to start is by inspecting [Z3's cpp example file](https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/blob/master/examples/c%2B%2B/example.cpp) and gradually create your "Hello Z3 world" examples. Simply get inside your `build` directory and run `make examples`. once make completes successfully, simply run `./cpp_example`. I see that your example is taken from their first function `demorgan`, so if it doesn't work for you, maybe it's best to post it in [their issues](https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/issues).

EDIT:

I've just tested it and it works fine.
Maybe tell us how you compiled your example?

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer.

Comment: @IgorR. Gracefully disagree ... it contains a practical guide towards solving the problem in the post - start from Z3's examples and work your way through until you reach your version ... somewhere along the line the problem will introduce itself more clearly.